# Search on Power BI reports using sql

Tags: powerbi, power-bi-report-server

I'm wondering if there was an easy way to search for a specific keyword in a
Power bi report datasources (published on a Report Server) ?

For report developped with report builder, we can do this by using something like

```
CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),CONVERT(XML,CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX),Content)))
```

but the COntent field in dbo.catalog table is always empty for Power BI reports. I'm looking for Power BI reports that don't use tabular or SSAS model, but sql datasource.

this will help to locate all power bi reports that refers to a specific table, function...

thanks in advance

... no answer .. means not so easily feasable ?